How to implement usePrevious in React v19 without referencing ref.current during render?
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export const usePrevious = (value: unknown) => {
  const ref = useRef<unknown>();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });

  return ref.current;
};

This is the hook that I used to use.
However, after upgrading to React v19, I am now getting error:

Ref values (the current property) may not be accessed during render. (https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef)eslint(react-compiler/react-compiler)

What's the correct way to implement without it?

Related issue

There may be better solutions out there for this, but as a workaround, I handled this issue by creating a class that holds current/prev values:
/* usePrevious.ts */

import { useMemo } from 'react';

type EqCheck<X> = (prev: X, curr: X) => boolean;
const shallowEqual = <X>(prev: X, curr: X) => prev === curr;

/*
 * basic class to hold the current and previous values;
 * does eq-check internally, though that could be offloaded
 * into the hook body if necessary
 */
class QuasiRef<X> {
  previous: X | undefined;
  current: X;
  isEqual: EqCheck<X>;
  constructor(initial: X, isEq: EqCheck<X> = shallowEqual) {
    this.current = initial;
    this.isEqual = isEq;
  }

  eval = (currentVal: X) => {
    if (!this.isEqual(this.current, currentVal)) this.onChange(currentVal);
  };

  onChange = (newValue: X) => {
    this.previous = this.current;
    this.current = newValue;
  };
}

export function usePrevious<X>(currentValue: X, isEq?: EqCheck<X>): X | undefined {
  /* create a new instance of the pseudo-ref class for this hook implemention */
  const ValRef = useMemo(() => new QuasiRef(currentValue, isEq), []);

  /*
   * eval equality on every render;
   * this could also be done in a useLayoutEffect or something if 
   * over-computing is a concern.
   */
  ValRef.eval(currentValue);

  return ValRef.previous;
}

The actual advantage of this approach over using a useState hook (as suggested in the useRef docs [Pitfall] and notes on preserving information across renders) is marginal [it alleviates the 1-render-cycle gap between when the value changes and the previous value is updated], but in rare cases where it's necessary, this hook has done the trick so far.
